# Rundeck + powershell inline script issue

Tags: powershell, rundeck, winrm

I'm new to rundeck and i'm trying to make it work in my environnement.

- Rundeck server is on Ubuntu server.
- Remote nodes are Windows Server.

All the winrm https / kerberos part is done and seems to work.

I have made a job with an inline script step which exports data from AD in a csv file.

The issue is that rundeck removes @ caracter in the script thus it does not work.

source definition :

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=...,DC=com" -Filter {mail -like "*@xxxx.com"} | select @{Name="NOM";Expression={$_.Surname}},@{Name="PRENOM";Expression={$_.Givenname}},@{Name="SERVICE";Expression={$_.wWWHomePage}},@{Name="BATIMENT";Expression={$_.wWWHomePage}},@{Name="EMAIL";Expression={$_.UserPrincipalName}},@{Name="TELEPHONE";Expression={$_.wWWHomePage}} | sort Nom | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File "D:\Data\OUT\Export.csv"
```

On the remote node :

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=...,DC=com" -Filter {mail -like "*@xxxx.com"} | select {Name="PRENOM";Expression={$_.Givenname}},{Name="BATIMENT";Expression={$_.wWWHomePage}},{Name="TELEPHONE";Expression={$_.wWWHomePage}} | sort Nom | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File "D:\Data\OUT\Export.csv"
```

How to prevent this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try escaping the literal `@`'s in the script source definition with `\@`

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation, you need to use `@@` to escape the `@`. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#script-usage) and find the "Escaping Replacement Token" section.